# anible loops and subdictionaries

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to loop through some parameters in Ansible using a jinja template and a yaml variable file.
The content of the jinja template isn't important here, but I can share a version of the playbook and the yaml variable file below.

What I want to be able to do is generate 4 files, each of them with the name of the peer in the filename.  At the moment the playbook works, but generates one file called test-peers.  I've tried with_nested and with_subelements - subelements only seems to want to work with a list rather than a dictionary, and I can't find a way to list the values within peers with with_nested.  Is there a solution to this?

The YAML file:

```yaml
customer: test_customer
routers:
  router1:
    router_number: 01
    router_model: ISR4431
    peers:
      America:
        hostname: America
        priority: Primary
        number: 1
      Asia:
        hostname: Asia
        priority: Backup
        number: 2
  router2:
    router_number: 02
    router_model: ISR4431
    peers:
      America:
        hostname: America
        priority: Primary
        number: 1
      Asia:
        hostname: Asia
        priority: Backup
        number: 2
```

The task in the playbook:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: WAN gateway testing
    template:
      src: my.template.j2
      dest: "{{ 'config/' + customer + '-' + item.1 }}"
    with_nested:
      - "{{ routers }}"
      - peers
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to transform your data structure to something you can use the intended way. Here is one possible way to do it in the below playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    customer: test_customer
    # Your orig data on a single json line for compactness
    routers: {"router1": {"router_number": 1, "router_model": "ISR4431", "peers": {"America": {"hostname": "America", "priority": "Primary", "number": 1}, "Asia": {"hostname": "Asia", "priority": "Backup", "number": 2}}}, "router2": {"router_number": 2, "router_model": "ISR4431", "peers": {"America": {"hostname": "America", "priority": "Primary", "number": 1}, "Asia": {"hostname": "Asia", "priority": "Backup", "number": 2}}}}
  tasks:
    - name: Transform our dict to something easier to loop with subelements
      vars:
        current_router:
          router_number: "{{ item.router_number }}"
          router_model: "{{ item.router_model }}"
          peers: "{{ item.peers | dict2items | map(attribute='value') }}"
      set_fact:
        routers_transformed: "{{ routers_transformed | default([]) + [current_router] }}"
      loop: "{{ routers | dict2items | map(attribute='value') }}"

    - name: Show the transformed data
      debug:
        var: routers_transformed

    - name: Create a file name for each router/peer association in the structure as per requirement
      debug:
        msg: "Filename would be config/{{ customer }}/router{{ item.0.router_number }}/{{ item.1.hostname}}"
      loop: "{{ routers_transformed | subelements('peers') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "router {{ item.0.router_number }} for peer {{ item.1.hostname }}"
```

which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Transform our dict to something easier to loop with subelements] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'router_number': 1, 'router_model': 'ISR4431', 'peers': {'America': {'hostname': 'America', 'priority': 'Primary', 'number': 1}, 'Asia': {'hostname': 'Asia', 'priority': 'Backup', 'number': 2}}})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'router_number': 2, 'router_model': 'ISR4431', 'peers': {'America': {'hostname': 'America', 'priority': 'Primary', 'number': 1}, 'Asia': {'hostname': 'Asia', 'priority': 'Backup', 'number': 2}}})

TASK [Show the transformed data] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "routers_transformed": [
        {
            "peers": [
                {
                    "hostname": "America",
                    "number": 1,
                    "priority": "Primary"
                },
                {
                    "hostname": "Asia",
                    "number": 2,
                    "priority": "Backup"
                }
            ],
            "router_model": "ISR4431",
            "router_number": "1"
        },
        {
            "peers": [
                {
                    "hostname": "America",
                    "number": 1,
                    "priority": "Primary"
                },
                {
                    "hostname": "Asia",
                    "number": 2,
                    "priority": "Backup"
                }
            ],
            "router_model": "ISR4431",
            "router_number": "2"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Create a file name for each router/peer association in the structure as per requirement] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=router 1 for peer America) => {
    "msg": "Filename would be config/test_customer/router1/America"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=router 1 for peer Asia) => {
    "msg": "Filename would be config/test_customer/router1/Asia"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=router 2 for peer America) => {
    "msg": "Filename would be config/test_customer/router2/America"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=router 2 for peer Asia) => {
    "msg": "Filename would be config/test_customer/router2/Asia"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: that's really good - is there a way to restructure the original yaml file to get the same result?

Comment: simply use the structure shown in the debug dump of `routers_transformed` if ti suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*Restructure the original yaml file.*"**

A: Use template. For example

```yaml
shell> cat templates/routers.j2
customer: {{ customer }}
routers:
  {{ routers2|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
```

The tasks below do the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        routers2: "{{ routers2|default({})|
                      combine({item.0.key: item.0.value|
                                           combine({'peers': item.1})}) }}"
      loop: "{{ routers|dict2items|zip(peers)|list }}"
      vars:
        peers: "{{ routers|json_query('*.peers')|
                   map('dict2items')|
                   map('json_query', '[].value')|list }}"
    - template:
        src: routers.j2
        dest: routers.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat routers.yml 
customer: test_customer
routers:
  router1:
      peers:
      -   hostname: America
          number: 1
          priority: Primary
      -   hostname: Asia
          number: 2
          priority: Backup
      router_model: ISR4431
      router_number: '01'
  router2:
      peers:
      -   hostname: America
          number: 1
          priority: Primary
      -   hostname: Asia
          number: 2
          priority: Backup
      router_model: ISR4431
      router_number: '02'
```

Then the loop below

```yaml
    - include_vars: routers.yml
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ item.0.router_number }}
          {{ item.0.router_model }}
          {{ item.1.hostname }}
          {{ item.1.number }}
          {{ item.1.priority }}
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ routers }}"
        - peers
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 01 ISR4431 America 1 Primary
  msg: 01 ISR4431 Asia 2 Backup
  msg: 02 ISR4431 America 1 Primary
  msg: 02 ISR4431 Asia 2 Backup
```

Comment: Excellent, this is the answer I ended up going with, though it was more restructuring my yaml and my previous templates.  Thankyou